# How to troubleshoot intermittent Azure SQL performance issues

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database

I'm running an Azure SQL instance behind an Azure Web App, both of which run perfectly fine the majority of the time.  At seemingly random intervals (ever few days or so), the database DTUs peg out completely.  How would I trouble shoot the source of these problems?  I think it's related to a sudden influx of requests from the server, but I can't figure out exactly where/how.

According to the "Performance Metrics" in Azure, the offending metrics seem to be

- Data I/O
- Log I/O
- Increased connection count
- Tempdb file size

Again, I *think* it might be caused by the server all of a sudden sending a ton of requests, but I have no idea how to validate that or how to trace the request sources that are causing this.

Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the reports in Querystore.
Set a timespan that includes a time when it ran both well and badly and then examine the various metrics. Were there more executions during the bad period, Did some queries get a bad plan and cause resource problems - if so it is easy to force the better plan.

Answer (score 0):

**I have no idea how to validate that or how to trace the request sources that are causing this.**

You can do it using any of these 2 methods:

1. Use an extended event trace and collect hostname for each session. You already know that you have an increased workload. This will tell what hosts are the source of the increased workload. If you need a tutorial on the extended events I find [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/extended-events-workbench/) by Phil is a good one.
2. Turn on [Azure SQL Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview) which gives details for each completed batch

If you want more details set setup [diagnostic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/metrics-diagnostic-telemetry-logging-streaming-export-configure?tabs=azure-portal). Once your data is collected for a while you use the ['AzureSQLAnalytics' solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/azure-sql) to see built-in graphs and datasets. You can also use [Kusto Query Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/) to query raw data.